# How can I arrange my table so that it can fit in a vertical A4 format?

Tags: tables

I was putting my data into a table for one document and unfortunately, my table is too long to fit in an A4 format. The document is mandatory in vertical and I am not sure how to arrange this data without it does not look good. If someone has a suggestion that could keep the format and the type of table that I am using, I would be very thankful.

My code is the following:

```
         \begin{center}
                \hspace*{-5cm}
                
                \begin{tabular}{||c c c c c c c c c c||} 
                    \hline
                    Sample Nr. & PPV 9nm & PEDOT 20nm & $MoO_{3}$ 3nm  & P-TPD 10nm & PMMA 6 nm & PPP 20nm & PVK 20nm & TPBi 25nm & ZnO 25nm \\ [0.5ex] 
                    \hline\hline
                    1 & 25.95 & 40.83 & 28 & 94.50 & 24.44 & 30.22 & 25.54 & 26.45 & 36.43 \\ 
                    \hline
                    2 & 19.09 & 28.02 & 11.32 & 94.43 & 16.41 & 17.42 & 18.72 & 18.67 & 25.52\\
                    \hline
                    3 & 8.68 & 12.08 & 21.76 & 8.78 & 9.92 & 11.72 & 8.89 & 9.27 & 10.77 \\  [1ex] 
                    \hline
                    
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
            \end{center}
```

And as you might expect the table is too long for an A4 format and the table is cut and looks like this:

[image]

Do you have any suggestions to arrange all the data and can be easily understood?

Thanks for all your suggestions

Comment: You could split the information in all column headers into two lines in order to save some space.

Comment: For an extensive list on various techniques with which you can make sure a table fits into the available space, take a look at [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144)  For more specific advice on how to apply thouse techniques to your table, please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and add it to your question. Making sure a table fits into the available space is impossible without knowing how much space there is.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your table. From your fragment we can't repriduce your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my suggestion based on allowing line breaks in the column headers. For this, I used `\thead` from the `makecell` package.

[image]

Additionally, I also used `booktabs` for horizontal lines with improved spacing, `siunitx` for numbers and units, as well as for an ipmroved alignment of numbers inside of the table columns, as well as `chemformula` to correctly typeset chemical formulae.

Since there was no documentclass given in the original code, I guessed one. If the table still exceeds the linewidth in your document, feel free to adjust the font size, e.g. by commenting out `\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}`, and by adding `\small` inside of `table`. If the table is still too wide, you could try to reduce the horizontal white space between the columns, for example by using something like `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{c *{9}{S[table-format=2.2]}} 
    \toprule
    {\thead{Sample\\ Nr.}} 
      & {\thead{PPV\\ \SI{9}{\nm}}}    & {\thead{PEDOT\\ \SI{20}{\nm}}} & {\thead{\ch{MoO_{3}}\\ \SI{3}{\nm}}}  
      & {\thead{P-TPD\\ \SI{10}{\nm}}} & {\thead{PMMA\\ \SI{6}{\nm}}}   & {\thead{PPP\\ \SI{20}{\nm}}}
      & {\thead{PVK\\ \SI{20}{\nm}}}   & {\thead{TPBi\\ \SI{25}{\nm}}}  & {\thead{ZnO\\ \SI{25}{\nm}}} \\
    \midrule
    1 & 25.95 & 40.83 & 28    & 94.50 & 24.44 & 30.22 & 25.54 & 26.45 & 36.43 \\ 
    2 & 19.09 & 28.02 & 11.32 & 94.43 & 16.41 & 17.42 & 18.72 & 18.67 & 25.52 \\
    3 & 8.68  & 12.08 & 21.76 & 8.78  & 9.92  & 11.72 & 8.89  & 9.27  & 10.77 \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
            
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

For the table you posted, the easiest way to accomplish this is transposition, as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn1c{#1}}
\newcommand{\nm}[1]{\SI{#1}{\nano\meter}}
\begin{document}
     \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{lSSS}
        \toprule
            Sample Nr.       & \mc1  & \mc2  & \mc3  \\
        \midrule
            PPV \nm{9}       & 25.95 & 19.09 & 8.68  \\
            PEDOT \nm{20}    & 40.83 & 28.02 & 12.08 \\
            \ce{MoO3} \nm{3} & 28    & 11.32 & 21.76 \\
            P-TPD \nm{10}    & 94.5  & 94.43 & 8.78  \\
            PMMA \nm{6}      & 24.44 & 16.41 & 9.92  \\
            PPP \nm{20}      & 30.22 & 17.42 & 11.72 \\
            PVK \nm{20}      & 25.54 & 18.72 & 8.89  \\
            TPBi \nm{25}     & 26.45 & 18.67 & 9.27  \\
            ZnO \nm{25}      & 36.43 & 25.52 & 10.77 \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've made a few other changes as well:

- the `booktabs` package is used to create a visually appealing table using `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`.
- the second to fourth column are formatted using the `S` column type from the `siunitx` package, which aligns numbers taking the decimal point into account. (For the sample numbers, this is changed to a `c` column using `\multicolumn`.)
- the chemical compound `MoO3` is typeset using `\ce` ("chemical expression", I think) from the very useful and versatile `mhchem` package. (For `ZnO` etc. it makes no difference, visually.)
- `\SI`, again from `situnitx`, is used to typeset those nanometer figures. I've defined a shortcut, `\nm`, to avoid having to type `\SI{...}{\nano\meter}` all the time.

I hope that this helps!

If your full table contains many more samples, BTW, I would still suggest doing it this way, but splitting up the table and only putting a certain number of samples -- say, eight, or however many you can fit onto a page -- into each individual table.

There's a limit to how much information can be conveyed to the reader using a single table, and there's a point where a single large table -- as opposed to several smaller ones -- is no longer optimal.